# Mockito - Custom Matcher throws NPE when trying to match primitive

Tags: java, mockito

Trying to figure out how to write a custom matcher for a primitive value.  Say I've got the following custom matcher:

```
class IsEven extends ArgumentMatcher<Integer> {
    public boolean matches(Object i) {
        return ((Integer) i) % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

And I run the following test.  'mocked' is an already-mocked instance of a class that has a method 'someMethod':

```
@Test
public void primatives() {

    mocked.someMethod(2);

    ArgumentMatcher<Integer> customMatcher = new IsEven();

    // ! Throws NPE !
    Mockito.verify(mocked).someMethod(Mockito.argThat(customMatcher));

}
```

The reason for the NullPointerException is that the Mockio.argThat method always returns a null, which I'm guessing cannot be autoboxed back into an integer.

I feel as though this woudl be a common use case - any advice?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.. Reading Javadoc helps:

In rare cases when the parameter is a primitive then you *must* use relevant intThat(), floatThat(), etc. method.  This way you will avoid NullPointerException during autounboxing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use doThrow(), doAnswer(), doNothing(), doReturn() and doCallRealMethod() in place of the corresponding call with when(), for any method. It is necessary when you

stub void methods
stub methods on spy objects (see below)
stub the same method more than once, to change the behaviour of a mock in the middle of a test.
but you may prefer to use these methods in place of the alternative with when(), for all of your stubbing calls.

```
   when(mock.foo()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

   //Impossible: the exception-stubbed foo() method is called so RuntimeException is thrown.
   when(mock.foo()).thenReturn("bar");

   //You have to use doReturn() for stubbing:
   doReturn("bar").when(mock).foo();
```